# Force synchronous XMLHttpRequest / Ajax without warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Ok so obviously [synchronous has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) because it is bad for the user experience.

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

And we all know that. But I still want to use it for something completely different than the user experience, on the development side. I understand they don't want it used, but why remove the feature? These kind of things should be accesible via the "non-default" configuration via the options symbolizer. IMO it will be reversed one day.

Anyway, the question is: What kind of hack can I use to emulate synchronous Ajax or XMLHttpRequest, without receiving the warning message? My assumption is eventually it won't work in the browsers once they fully deprecate it.

Comment: In what context do you truly need a blocking wait? You could just do a timeout loop that keeps checking if there has been a response.

Comment: Because I'm using a dynamic clientside require module loader for development purposes (dependo). The timeout loop doesn't work it hangs the browser and the xml request never finishes. We have many small modules and like to develop with zero build configuration on the abstracted sub-modules.

Comment: Why doesn't the timeout loop work? It is asynchronous and therefore shouldn't be hanging anything? As far as I know it isn't really possible to totally block in JS. You could probably just count to a million over and over to block....

Comment: Why do you care? Just ignore the warning.

Comment: Because my assumption is I will wake up one day and it won't work... unless the browsers don't plan on removing it then I guess there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @WayOfTheFuture I agree it is something you should be concerned with. You are writing client-side code? When JS is busy blocking it freezes the browser (or at least tab). Why is this ever desired behavior?

Comment: Even if it was busy loading modules, I would never want any of my tabs frozen and unable to close while loading any website.

Comment: it's all local it loads in a split second

Comment: so imagine a large project with 10 sub directory projects, each one a browserify module with index.js entry point... with different people working on different modules and some not allowed to see certain modules. I can setup browserify and watchify with package.json for each one, then have an independent build for each, which makes development a pain, or can use drq and only maintain one package.json in the root folder. build step for production no build step for development. just save the file and the browser reloads no build.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: **This solution doesn't work.** I'll leave it here to discourage trying a similar method. If someone can actually find a working solution, I'll remove this answer.

<strike>If you really want to fake a synchronous ajax request, you can use jQuery's [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function, and just keep checking if an asynchronous request is complete.</strike>

```
function fakeSynchronous(ajaxSettings) {
  var promise = $.ajax(ajaxSettings);
  while (promise.state() === "pending") {
    $("html").delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I see that now too. I'll see if I can come up with something else later.